# Uncaught TypeError: Tv(...).sandboxEvaluator is not a function throws at aura_prod.js:61:3687

Tags: custom

We have a managed package that our customers install. Recently one of our customers responded that it started not working, and the error they see is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Tv(...).sandboxEvaluator is not a function throws at xxxxxx/aura_prod.js:61:3687
```

We don't have `sandboxEvaluator` in any place in our code, and I wonder how I should fix this as we didn't change our code, and it suddenly started to fail for some customers.

I have an instance of salesforce where this error doesn't happen, and the app functions correctly. Where can I look to find any clue about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sandboxEvaluator` is a part of Salesforce's security system. If you turn on Debug Mode, you'll see that `Tv` is actually a function called `createRootWindowSandboxRecord$LWS` (if you have Lightning Web Security enabled in your org and in Lightning Debug Mode). It's purpose is to create a secure sandbox for a component (called a "record" in the code). It's important to note that most of this code is only protected by a few top-level try-catch blocks, so any little uncaught exception can easily end up killing the entire render cycle. This is rather annoying to debug, but it's what we have to work with.

There could be a number of things, some of which you'll need login access to the subscriber for.

First, check the Speed Test page ([Production](https://login.salesforce.com/speedtest.jsp) | [Sandbox](https://test.salesforce.com/speedtest.jsp)) to see what patch versions each org is on (the working and non-working one). If the non-working ones are on a lower patch version, that means the bug will resolve itself. If the non-working ones are on a higher patch version, this means a feature, bug, or bug fix is upcoming that may break the app for the rest of the orgs.

Second, check Setup | Security | Session Settings, and see if each org is using Lightning Web Security. If there is a difference, change the settings in the working or non-working org and see if that clears the error. If so, you have a security-specific error, and a way to reproduce that. Locker Service and Lightning Web Security are fundamentally different systems, so it's possible for a bug to be in one and not the other. Note that I would check this toggle even if there's a difference in patch versions, because that might be culprit.

Third, I'd check the installed package versions between the non-working and working orgs. If the non-working one is a lower version, try upgrading. If the non-working one is a higher version, check your recent updates and see if maybe a bug was introduced in the package. It could be a bug that got past QA, or maybe it's only because of the patch version or security mode settings that could have caused it. Make sure you're testing both LS/LWS modes before updating your package to a new version.

Fourth, in the broken org, you can try debugging live. First, turn on Debug Mode for your user in Setup | Custom Code | Lightning Components | Debug Mode. Next, go to the F12 Developer Console, click on Sources, then click on the "Pause on exception" and check "Pause on all exceptions", then reload the page. You will see one caught exception that throws "foo", this is a feature test. After that, you shouldn't get any more exceptions. If you do, it will hopefully pause on the line of code that's causing the problem. You should be able to fix it from there.

In any case, you need to figure out if it's a bug in your code or Salesforce. If there is a difference of patch versions, LS/LWS, etc, you'll need to figure out if it's a bug in your code or Salesforce. Typically, it is a package bug, not Salesforce. However, doing a F12 debug with Debug Mode turned on should provide enough details to determine if you have code to fix, or if there is a bug to report.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! The security setting difference was the case

Comment: We're suddenly seeing this error on Visualforce pages with aura components that use ltng:require to include scripts if LWS is on. With debug mode on, the component works as expected. With debug mode off, the included script is never run and we get this error.

Comment: We're no longer seeing this issue in environments on Spring '23 Patch 13.1, but it is present in those still on on Spring '23 Patch 12.4, so chances are Salesforce broke it and then fixed it.